# yaml_cpp: Converting NULL to std::vector<double>

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

I got some .yaml files which have some NULL values in the lists, e.g.:

```
  Src_1:
    A_Coeff: ~
    B_Coeff:
      - -0.0007726139317399502
    Source_Direction:
      - -0.3588391810596386
      - -0.8148504694940865
      - 0.4552506504092068
    Source_Position:
      - 0.002637567823932366
      - 0.3725416725539
      - 0.09719412496423192
```

The conversion of A_Coeff to a native std::vector was done like this in the code I have:

```
YAML::Node systemDefinition = YAML::LoadFile(fileName);
std::vector<double> coeff = systemDefinition[srcTag]["A_Coeff"].as< std::vector<double> >();
```

They used version 0.5.3 of yaml-cpp from source. I tried using 0.5.9 from source. If I read the code the same way as before, I'm getting an error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'YAML::TypedBadConversion<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >' what(): yaml-cpp: error at line 144, column 14: bad conversion
```

Obviously, the NULL can not be converted to the vector. I'm not finding many information about the parsing of NULL except this one: https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/issues/590. But there, they don't seem to have a problem with the tilde.

Therefore, I'm wondering: Is this conversion from NULL to a native data type valid and how should it work? Was there a change on how NULL gets parsed?

Comment: I think you're right that it's 0.5.2 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libyaml-cpp-dev)

Comment: Should be able to bisect the git changes between those versions

Comment: Seems to be some `null` stuff in the diff between 0.5.2 and 0.5.3 already. It's from 2015 ... I'd say, clone it from github and compile it. It's done in 2 minutes, really.

Comment: Had a quick scan of the revision history and nothing really stands out to me but if you just check out the source, build, test, skip ahead a year or so, build, test, skip back six months, build, test, you should quite quickly find the change that caused it. Then the commit message for that change might lead to more information, or at least you have a starting point. All of this should only take a few minutes unless the build takes ages.

Comment: It builds really fast :) `time (cmake ..;make -j)` (which includes building the tests) = 59 seconds.

Comment: I‘m using ROS, which uses the yaml-cpp system dependency. Need to figure out how to replace this. I‘m also wondering what‘s happening now after I have several versions of the library, i.e. the apt and two different Cmake builds...

Comment: Ok, after testing 0.5.2, 0.5.3 and 0.5.9, it seems like parsing a tilde was removed after 0.5.3. At least it's not working anymore in 0.5.9. I'm wondering why...

Comment: Well `~` is interpreted as `NULL` and that is not a valid value of `std::vector<>` (because it's not a pointer), so this is what I'd expect to happen (I don't know the actual reason for the change though). Can you replace it with `[]` in the YAML file?

Comment: Yes, I‘m sure that‘s the reason. But changing every .yaml file is currently not a good option. It seems like people are using this NULL.